# What am I doing wrong? Setter for private variable does not substitute the value

Tags: java, variables, private, getter-setter

I have a calculator program and in the main application, it asks the user for a number. Immediately the number should be set to the current value. My current value is a double that lives inside of a "Display" class

The syntax looks like this

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
double userNumber = input.nextDouble(); 
sciCalc.display.setCurrentValue(userNumber);
```

This is a snippet of the Display.java class and setCurrentValue() method.

```
 private double currentValue = 0.0;
-
-//skipping to the method 
-
public void setCurrentValue(Double num){
        currentValue = num;
    }
```

The order of my program asks user for a number and then adds them together with a seperate add function that utilizes "getCurrentValue()"... however the add just adds the number to 0 because the setter is not updating the variable. How can I fix this... This is an example of the terminal outputs...

```
* Welcome to your new Scientific Calculator! Please enter a number:
* 4
>sciCalc.display.setCurrentValue(4.0);
* The number you entered is: 4.0
* Enter a second number:
* 5
* The number you entered is 5.0 
>sciCalc.mathfeatures.add(5.0);
* 5.0 //- should be 9???
```

What can I do here?

EDIT
I was asked to add the add function

```
public Double add(Double num){
    return num + getCurrentValue();
}
```

```
public double getCurrentValue(){
        return currentValue;
    }
```

Comment: How are you creating/setting the objects for `sciCalc` and `display`? And you aren't creating a `Scanner` every time you want to read, are you?

Comment: Can you post the code the mathfeatures.add() code?

Comment: Yes, you need to shoe more complete code, including `getCurrentValue`

Comment: I've added the code

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [mre]. Showing code is a lot more helpful than describing it. Please [edit] your question to include your code, sample input and output, and any error messages. Tell us what you expect to happen as well as what's actually happening. This will help us answer your question better.

Comment: As @JohnKugelman says, we need to see the complete code. I suspect that you have a field named `currentValue` in two of your classes, and you are setting the one in Display and then using the one in MathFeatures, but that is just a guess.